# How to turn a numpy array into an graph with igraph?

Tags: python

Lets say I have a numpy array

```
arr = np.array([1,2,3,4,5,6,7])
```

how would I go about turning this array into a graph with igraph.

Comment: Please clarify, since a graph needs both vertices and edges do you just want a graph with the vertices 1 through 7 or something else?

Answer (score 1):

In igraph you can use ***igraph.Graph.Adjacency*** to create a graph from an adjacency matrix without having to use zip.

know that igraph.Graph.Adjacency can't take an *np.array* as argument, but that is easily solved using tolist.
An example of how to do it:

```
import igraph
import pandas as pd

node_names = ['A', 'B', 'C']
a = pd.DataFrame([[1,2,3],[3,1,1],[4,0,2]], index=node_names, columns=node_names)

# Get the values as np.array, it's more convenenient.
A = a.values

# Create graph, A.astype(bool).tolist() or (A / A).tolist() can also be used.
g = igraph.Graph.Adjacency((A > 0).tolist())

# Add edge weights and node labels.
g.es['weight'] = A[A.nonzero()]
g.vs['label'] = node_names  # or a.index/a.columns
```

Try it with your own values of vertices and edges since you didn't specify enough information.